# Команда не найдена

Tags: bash, docker

Недавно начал изучать кластеризацию, и виртуализацию. При прочтение руководств, наткнулся на проблему. У меня отсутствует команда FROM и COPY. Использую официальные руководство. Как исправить данную проблему?

[Тык](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx)

Comment: Объясните, почему вы решили, что команда отсутсвует? Где вы ее вводите?

Comment: Windows 10, Docker ToolBox. Даже  внутри докера, отсутствует данная команда. 

1. 
https://sun9-22.userapi.com/impg/dTlax7ExzIhLuoiv3c7y-H3oc7Iv2GNVj1mWVw/K1sUu1H7VZA.jpg?size=981x475&quality=96&sign=4484c856aa37f188ccb7786a96a41350&type=album
2. 
https://sun9-34.userapi.com/impg/W7AAKopQVQGuyutLAypq1yvMFNBE2Ye0gr1ygQ/1yFTOhspd5E.jpg?size=720x442&quality=96&sign=13edf2131464ac68b8629b8d6e14f86e&type=album

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю данные команды описываются в файле "DockerFile" пример ниже

```
FROM "Название докер имейджа"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
git \
python3-pip
RUN pip3 install colorama
RUN pip3 install requests
WORKDIR /usr/bin/app
COPY . .
```